# Stripe_ruby Unable to store card_last4 and card_type after successful customer creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

After creating a customer successfully, I can inspect the object with:

```
Rails.logger.debug("single card object has: #{customer.cards.data.card.inspect}")
```

which returns a json like this:

```
#<Stripe: : Customer: 0x2801284>JSON: {
    "id": "cus_2WXxmvhBJgSmNY",
    "object": "customer",
    "cards": {
      "object": "list",
       "data": [
           {
              "id": "card_2WXxcCsdY0Jjav",
               "object": "card",
               "last4": "4242",
               "type": "Visa",
               "exp_month": 1,
               "exp_year": 2014,
           }
        ]
           },
     "default_card": "card_2WXxcCsdY0Jjav"
 }
```

But I will do **Customer.cards.data.last4**  it gives a **NOMethodError**.

If I remove the **last4** and just call **Customer.cards.data**, it gives

```
#<Stripe: : Card: 0x1ed7dc0>JSON: {
      "id": "card_2Wmd80yQ76XZKH",
      "object": "card",
      "last4": "4242",
      "type": "Visa",
      "exp_month": 1,
      "exp_year": 2015,
 }
```

Now I seem to have the direct card object but if I do

```
   card =  Customer.cards.data
   self.last4 = card.last4
```

I still get a **noMethodError**

Here is shortened version of my model:

```
     class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
         def create_customer_in_stripe(params)
             if self.user.stripe_card_token.blank?
               user_email = self.user.email
               customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: user_email, card: params[:token])
               card  = customer.cards.data

               self.card_last4  = card.last4
               self.card_type = card.type
               self.card_exp_month = card.exp_month
               self.card_exp_year = card.exp_year
               self.user.save
          end
          self.save!
       end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customer.cards`, as the name implies, returns *multiple* cards in an array.

You can't call card accessor methods because you don't have a Stripe::Card object; you have an *array* of Stripe::Card objects. You need to either call `customer.cards.first` (the most likely answer) or iterate over the array for a specific card you're looking for.

Once you have a Stripe::Card object, all the accessor methods will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Does calling **first** always return the lat card created.

Comment: `first` will always be the first array item (like any other Ruby array). Stripe doesn't guarantee any given ordering, so if there are multiple cards it could be any card. In this particular case, since you're at signup, there's probably only one card to choose from and it'll always be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

`cself.card_last4  = card.last4` should be `self.card_last4  = card["last4"]` as the gem itself doesn't have a `last4` method when searching on github.  I know i have to use `Hash syntax`.

I have a feeling that all of your methods on `card` will need this syntax.

EDit:

So it sounds like your model's last4 column is an integer, do `card["last4"].to_i` or change the migration to a string column in the DB.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code to use your suggested approach with **self.card_last4 = card["last4"]** but it now throws **TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)**. I tried **self.card_last4 = card["last4"].to_s** and threw the same **TypeError**

Comment: It doesn't have a lot of methods; they're dynamically generated from the JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

```
card =  Customer.cards.data

self.last4 = card[0].last4
```

Comment: Thanks this also works perfectly. Since I had accepted the first correct answer,  I decided to upvote yours, since it is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

how do you get the default active card in 
rails "default_card": "card_2WXxcCsdY0Jjav" in the list of customer.cards?

is there a better way rather than to loop thru customer.cards to get it or even easier way? 
Any pointers?

Hope this help someone who is wondering as well :- )

```
default_active_card = customer.cards.data.detect{|obj| obj[:id] == customer.default_card}
```

Comment: Never mind this question, since i found the answer to my own question...nice :- )  Hopefully this help someone who is wondering as well. default_active_card = customer.cards.data.detect{|obj| obj[:id] == customer.default_card}